# Expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, c++11

Совершенно непонятно, по какой причине компилятор выдает этот месседж...
Вот код, который вызывает сие поведение:

```
template<CalculateTypes calculateType>
auto lookup() ->
    decltype(std::get<Private::IndexOfList<calculateType, StrategyTypes...>::value>(_calculatingTuple))
{
    return std::get<Private::IndexOfList<calculateType, StrategyTypes...>::value>(_calculatingTuple);
}

template
<
    Calculating::CalculateTypes calculateType,
    class SourceDataType = typename calculating_list_type::template strategy_type_selector<calculateType>::source_data_type
>
auto calculate(const SourceDataType & sourceData) ->
    decltype(typename calculating_list_type::template strategy_type_selector<calculateType>::result_type())
{
    auto strategy = _calculates.lookup<calculateType>(); // В этом месте ошибка
    strategy.setSourceData(sourceData);
    strategy.calculate();

    return strategy.getResult();
}
```

ОС: Windows 8.1
Компилятор: mingw48_32

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=c++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE
```

Если кто поможет, буду очень признателен.

Comment: По крайней мере в этом фрагменте кода

    _calculates

не определено.

Comment: @Craft, в какой строке?

Comment: Ошибка в этом месте :

                   auto strategy = _calculates.lookup<calculateType>();

_calculates это член класса внутри функции, которого мы и исполняем все это, его тип данных: calculating_list_type

Answer (score 1):

`template<Calculating::CalculateTypes calculateType` - это не валидный синтаксис.
Должно быть `class|typename calculateType`.